# How do I connect with Python to a RESTful API using keys instead of basic authentication username and password?

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

I am new to programming, and was asked to take over a project where I need to change the current Python code we use to connect to a Ver 1 RESTful API. The company has switched to their Ver 2 of the API and now require IDs and Keys for authentication instead of the basic username and password. The old code that worked for the Ver 1 API looks like this:

```
import requests
import simplejson as json
import pprintpp as pprint

#API_Ver1 Auth
USER = 'username'
PASS = 'password'
url = 'https://somecompany.com/api/v1/groups'
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (USER, PASS)

r = json.loads(s.get(url).text)
groups = r["data"]
```

I can connect to the Ver 2 API via a terminal using a cURL string like this:

curl -v -X GET -H "X-ABC-API-ID:x-x-x-x-x" -H "X-ABC-API-KEY:nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn" 
-H "X-DE-API-ID:x" -H "X-DE-API-KEY:nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn" 
"https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/"

I have searched, but have been unsuccessful in finding a way to get the IDs and Keys from the cURL string to allow access to the Ver 2 API using Python. Thanks for your consideration in helping a noob get through this code change!

Answer (score 17):

you can add HTTP headers to a request

```
headers = {
    'X-ABC-API-ID': 'x-x-x-x-x',
    'X-ABC-API-KEY': 'nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn',
    'X-DE-API-ID': 'x',
    'X-DE-API-KEY': 'nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn'
}
r = requests.get('https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/', headers=headers)
```

Comment: how do i get valid x-api-key for a specific website, for example amazon.com? how are they generated?

Comment: @py_ios_dev That depends on the API.  For AWS for example, you want to go to IAM and request an API Key under the user's Security Credentials.