# How to get the request from api having account key

Tags: python, api

```
import requests
import json
def test_request_response():
    # Send a request to the API server and store the response.
    data = { 'username' : 'sxxxt@xxx.com', 'password' : 'xxxxe' }
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.get('https://xx.xxx.com/xx/xx',headers=headers,data=json.dumps(data))
    return response

test_request_response()
```

output

I have an api key also `API_KEY = '0x-x-x-x0` is there any I can give `API_KEY` in `requests.get` as like username and password

example in headers    `headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json','X-IG-API-KEY':'0x-x-x-x0'}`

Comment: Are you trying to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998640/how-do-i-connect-with-python-to-a-restful-api-using-keys-instead-of-basic-authen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

url = "https://api_url"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('apikey', '1234abcd')
files = {'filename': open('filename','rb')}

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers , auth=auth , files=files)
```

reference : [Calling REST API with an API key using the requests package in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075939/calling-rest-api-with-an-api-key-using-the-requests-package-in-python)